# status bar moved to the right at lower resolutions

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard

I'm having some trouble fixing this issue and can't seem to find an answer on it.

Below is a screenshot of my `storyBoard` and `viewController` - as you can see on the preview it's fine on iphone 8 but on the iphone SE the whole view is pushed a bit to the right including the status bar(you cant even see the battery)

What do I have to do to get the status bar and my header in the same position as ihpone 8?

I've tried various constraints but to no avail.

Hope you can help me,

Sincerely, Anton.

[image: my storyboard]

Comment: Probably just a bug in Xcode/Interface Builder. Does it look like that when running the app?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler The status bar looks correct in the simulator but the header labels are still floating a bit to the right. I've tried adding constraints but every constraint I create goes immediately red like an error even though it is the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your constraints. Your labels in header have no constraints right now. That's why they are on the same position for all screen sizes. You should add two constraints probably. One is `centeredHorizontally` and `centeredVertically` in container.